# Unable to start BonitaBPMCommunity-6.1.1

Tags: java, dll, business-process-management

I just installed BonitaBPMCommunity-6.1.1 without problems, but starting it up throws an error.

[image]

How to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you check that both Bonita BPM and Java are in 64bit?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested,

I uninstalled BonitaBPMCommunity-6.1.1, downloaded the [**Bonita BPM Default Package**](http://www.bonitasoft.com/how-we-do-it/downloads/bonita-bpm-default-package-0), unzipped it into a folder and now it is working.